# Self-referencing tables uses

Tags: database-design

What is the use of self-referencing tables ?

I came across the concept lately and I cannot find any simple example of it (every links on Google explain how to use it with many frameworks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self referencing tables can be used to store hierarchical data.  For example, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420885/how-do-i-design-a-database-to-store-properties-selecting-attributes-by-synonyms/7423459#7423459).

You can also use self referencing tables to record non-hierarchical relationships which are one-to-one.  For example, let's say you have a `PERSON` table and you want to have a relationship *is currently married to*.  You might model this with an intersection table, or you might use a simpler self referencing relationship.